# IN query with combination with 2 field

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a list of devices in cosmos DB documents (thousands), Make and SerialNumber is a unique identifier for each asset.

```
[{
    "make": "CAT",
    "serial": "A1",
    "NAME": "CAR"
},
{
    "make": "ZAT",
    "serial": "B1",
    "NAME": "BUS"
}, {
    "make": "CAT",
    "serial": "C1",
    "NAME": "TRUCK"
}, {
    "make": "ABC",
    "serial": "A1",
    "NAME": "Plane"
}, {
    "make": "ZAT",
    "serial": "A1",
    "NAME": "BIKE"
}
]
```

I need to get complete detail of Asset from the above documents based on below input device input.

```
[{
    "make": "CAT",
    "serial": "A1"
},
{
    "make": "ZAT",
    "serial": "B1"
}, {
    "make": "CAT",
    "serial": "C1"
}
]
```

I'm using below query to get complete detail(I know below query is incorrect). In general, I am getting passing 100s devices serial in a single query.

```
select * from t where serial in (A1,B1,C1) and make in (CAT,ZAT,CAT)
```

Is there any way to write IN query with combination with two fields?

**Expected Result**

A1 CAT

B1 ZAT

C1 CAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pankaj Rawat,please use this query sql,it could meet your requirements.

```
SELECT c FROM c where
ARRAY_CONTAINS([
    {"serialNumber":"A1","make":"CAT"},
    {"serialNumber":"B1","make":"ZAT"},
    {"serialNumber":"C1","make":"CAT"}
    ],
    {"serialNumber": c.serialNumber,
       "make":c.make}
    )
```

Output:

[image]